# Purpose of `render` in json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

In  json4s examples and documentation I often see the idioms

```
compact(render(jval))
```

and

```
pretty(render(jval))
```

I do not think I have actually seen an example with compact or pretty applied directly to a code generated `JValue`,
but it is not clear to me what `render` is doing here.
Render has type `JValue => JValue` and I do not see any obvious difference it makes
and running

```
json.take(100000).filter(x => compact(render(x)) != compact(x))
```

on some of my data returns an empty an empty collection.

**What does `render` actually do?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you were looking at one of the concrete implementations of the `render` method, which definition you can see in the [`JsonMethods trait`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.3/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonMethods.scala):

```
def render(value: JValue)(implicit formats: Formats = DefaultFormats): T
def compact(d: T): String
def pretty(d: T): String
```

The method `render` returns a generic type `T`, which is the entry type for the `compact` and `pretty` methods.

There are two implementations of the method `render` in the **json4s** project, as per the *native* and *jackson* flavours... I've checked the code superficially only but they both seem to be filtering the empty elements of the json object according to different strategies. Let's say getting it ready for the `pretty` and / or `compact` methods to kick in?